# when is a net a net of a solid?

Tags: graph-theory

Assume that you are given a net of 6 squares. Is there a simple
criterion (in terms of a few invariants that can be computed 
quickly) to tell whether it is the net of a cube?

More generally, when is an arbitrary net of faces the net of a solid?

Comment: what is a "net"?  do you mean a planar graph drawn (topologically) on a sphere?  or a graph that is topologically equivalent to the faces of a particular type of solid, with given edge lengths that are to be tested for consistency with geometric realization of the solid?

Comment: See http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/geometry-nets.html